# Angular input update validators

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm developing with angular 6, i've implemented an input as below (mat-input of angular material framework) and I've assigned id to a FormGroup validator. When I initialize typescript class I update input value but the validator doesn't see that and when I check it with this.formGroup.valid it returns false, but values are correct. Here is my code

```
constructor(...) {

    this.formGroup = formBuilder.group({
        id_conto: [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[0-9]+")],
        channel: [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[0-9]+")],
        automatic_size: [],
        pip_stoploss: [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[0-9]+")]
    });


    this.user = api.getUser();
    this.user.subscribe((response) => {
        this.userInstance = response;
    });

    this.editClicked();
}

editClicked() {
    if (this.formGroup.valid) {
        this.editing = !this.editing;
        if (!this.editing)
            this.formGroup.disable();
        else
        this.formGroup.enable();
    }
}
```

And my html code

```
<mat-form-field class="form-full-width">
          <input matInput placeholder="Channel" formControlName="channel"
                 [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" [value]="userInstance.channel">
          <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('channel').hasError('pattern') && !formGroup.get('channel').hasError('require')">
            Inserisci un valore numerico
          </mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('channel').hasError('require')">
            Inserire un valore
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You have to leave the field (`blur`) to see a view return saying you have an error. The form should be updated, but not the control itself. Consider giving a [mcve] on stackblitz.com

Comment: What do you mean with (blur)

Comment: `blur` is the opposite of `focus` : leave the input by clicking anywhere else, triggering a `blur` event

Comment: @AlesandroGiordano change it to required not require 

formGroup.get('channel').hasError('require')

Comment: @NarendraSinghRathore doesn't change anything

Comment: @trichetriche I want my control without clicking anywere... I'm checking it at the initialization

Comment: As told, your form will be invalid but not your control view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using reactive forms. To update a form control value, do it using your form object and not inside of your template.

Remove:

```
[value]="userInstance.channel"
```

Instead:

```
this.user.subscribe((response) => {
  this.userInstance = response;
  this.formGroup.controls.channel.setValue(this.userInstance.channel);
});
```

This should update the visible value too.